# Mongodb doesn't get restarted with subprocess call

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm trying to restart mongodb from a browser. Here is my code written with django framework:

```
def restart_db_mongo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        restart_cmd = ["sudo","systemctl","restart","mongodb"]
        p = subprocess.Popen(restart_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        (output, err) = p.communicate()
        if err is not None:
            return JsonResponse({"err_code":1,"err_description":str(err)},safe=False)
        status_cmd = ["sudo","systemctl","status","mongodb"]
        p = subprocess.Popen(status_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        (output, err) = p.communicate()
        if 'active (running)' in output:
            return JsonResponse({"err_code":0,"err_description":"Restarted successfully!"},safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"err_code":1,"err_description":str(err)},safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"err_code":2,"err_description":"Bad request"}, safe=False)
```

My problem is that mongodb doesn't get restarted. In fact, it finishes the first subprocess call without an error, but the status still remains inactive. In interactive environment, I've verified that the commands work. I'm using apache2 to run my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking apache2's log, I find out that I need to add `www-data` to the password-less list using `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. Now it works like a charm.